# OSGi and Gemini JPA: Using the Configuration Admin

Tags: java, configuration, osgi, eclipse-gemini

I am writing a small OSGi application for learning purposes.
I sucessfully set up Gemini JPA and the DBAccess Services to use JPA, and it is working fine, as long as i use a persistence.xml to configure my persistence units.

Then i stumbled across [This Example.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Gemini/JPA/Documentation/OtherTopics#Configuration_Admin) It seems like a really great feature to provide a persistence unit configuration at runtime. Except it is not working. I tried that exact code (for the Standalone Configuration), and it is executed, but nothing changes in the framework. As far as i understand, shouldn't there be a new service providing the new Persistence Unit?

I' am using the Equinox framework, all necessary bundles for gemini and dbaccess are installed and running, and the ConfigurationAdmin bundle (`org.eclipse.equinox.cm`) is installed and running at the point my code is executed.

I access the Configuration Admin like this:

```
ServiceReference<ConfigurationAdmin> s = context
            .getServiceReference(ConfigurationAdmin.class);
ConfigurationAdmin admin = context.getService(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a start order problem: the configuration must be created *before* the data source is looked-up for persistence. Try restarting your persistence bundle or change the start level of the persistence bundle to a higher level so it is started at a later time.

Furthermore, it may be handy to install the [Felix web console](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html) to see whether your configuration data is indeed registered with the configuration manager.

Comment: both is correct. I can see the registered config in the webconsole, and i also can not see a new Entitymanager-factory Service for this configuration as described in the question

Comment: Maybe you should post some more detail about the exact set-up and the properties you set. I think you still need to tell the JPA implementation that the bundle needs to be set-up for exporting an EMF since that is what you are currently seem to be missing.

Comment: Yes i think this may be the case, but i dont know how to do that. The turotial clearly states `...a standalone configuration is used only when there is no persistence descriptor in the persistence bundle`

Comment: According to the document you referred to, you must specify the `gemini.jpa.punit.bsn` property. Did you do that correctly? That is the only obvious reason I see why the JPA implementation did ignore the bundle completely.